# More information following 0xc0000139 error on windows

Tags: windows, dll, loader

I'm developing with Qt. Following a tiny change my program now will not start up and if I run the debugger, this dialog box is displayed:
[image]

I have looked at several other answers to questions about this error and Qt, and they all propose using a different compiler or a different version. I don't believe this will solve my problem.

Searching a little more diligently on Google, I came upon [this article](https://ofekshilon.com/2013/06/22/entry-point-not-found-and-other-dll-loading-problems/), about Visual C++ which suggests, very plausibly, that additional information is available but has been swallowed by one of the tools somewhere. The article goes on to suggest that by changing something in the registry, you can get additional information output when the error occurs. Now, I can run my program from the command line, with minimal intervening tools, so this looked like a really useful idea. Sadly, the link in the article that I believe will tell me more about the required registry change is dead.

Does this ring any bells with anyone? How can I found out the dll and entry point that isn't being found?

Comment: need set `ntdll.LdrpDebugFlags` (same as `ntdll.ShowSnaps`) to `0xffffffbf` and look debug output

Comment: Where do I set this value?

Comment: Or you can use `gflags` as mentioned on the same page. The other link you are asking about is probably the one archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141007063612/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/04/28/121871.aspx).

Comment: in debugger of course. in memory. you need have pdb symbols for ntdll.dll

Comment: Thank you @RbMm. How do I set this? Is it debugger dependant? I'm using gdb. How do I set this before the program fails to start up properly and doesn't give me a debugger prompt?

Comment: very easy - simply navigate to `ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags` memory address and set dword  to `0xffffffbf`

Comment: or paste binary exe for check it

Comment: Thanks @dxiv. I've installed `gflags` and used it to set "Show loader snaps" as suggested in the original article. I'm not getting any additional output now, even after a system reboot. The registry key mentioned in the second article doesn't exist on my Win10 system, even after changing `Windows NT` to `Windows`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to helpful comments, I managed to get the additional trace enabled using the "image files" tab of `gflags.exe`. I then found an *enormous* quantity of trace information on the "Debugger Log" tab of the QCreator debugger.

Close examination showed that the function containing the tiny chnge which kicked off this problem was failing to load.

I have no idea what caused this, but a clean rebuild of the program in question now allows it to run to the point of the original failure that made me want to make a tiny change in the first place.

I guess the moral of the story is to do a clean build immediately when things start getting weird - before trying to pin down the weirdness!